# Rolling means in Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop, array-broadcasting

I am trying to run some computations on DataFrames. I want to compute the average difference between two sets of rolling mean. To be more specific, the average of the difference between a long-term mean (`lst`) and a smaller-one (`lst_2`). I am trying to combine the calculation with a double for loop as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as pd

def main(df):

    df=df.pct_change()
    lst=[100,150,200,250,300]
    lst_2=[5,10,15,20]

    result=pd.DataFrame(np.sum([calc(df,T,t) for T in lst for t in lst_2]))/(len(lst)+len(lst_2))

    return result

def calc(df,T,t):

     roll=pd.DataFrame(np.sign(df.rolling(t).mean()-df.rolling(T).mean()))

     return roll
```

Overall I should have 20 differences (5 and 100, 10 and 100, 15 and 100 ... 20 and 300); I take the sign of the difference and I want the average of these differences at each point in time. Ideally the result would be a dataframe `result`.

I got the error: `cannot copy sequence with size 3951 to array axis with dimension 1056` when it runs the double for loops. Obviously I understand that due to rolling of different T and t, the dimensions of the dataframes are not equal when it comes to the array conversion (with `np.sum`), but I thought it would put "NaN" to align the dimensions.
Hope I have been clear enough. Thank you.

As requested in the comments, here is an example. Let's suppose the following
dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [100,101.4636,104.9477,106.7089,109.2701,111.522,113.3832,113.8672,115.0718,114.6945,111.7446,108.8154]},index=[0, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
df=df.pct_change()
```

and I have the following 2 sets of mean I need to compute:

```
lst=[8,10]
lst_1=[3,4]
```

Then I follow these steps:

1/
I want to compute the rolling mean(3) - rolling mean(8), and get the sign of it:

```
roll=np.sign(df.rolling(3).mean()-df.rolling(8).mean())
```

This should return the following:

```
roll = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN',-1,-1,-1,-1},index=[0, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
```

2/ 
I redo step 1 with the combination of differences 3-10 ; 4-8 ; 4-10. So I get overall 4 roll dataframes.

```
roll_3_8 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN',-1,-1,-1,-1},index=[0, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
roll_3_10 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN',-1,-1},index=[0, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
roll_4_8 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN',-1,-1,-1,-1},index=[0, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
roll_4_10 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN',-1,-1},index=[0, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
```

3/
Now that I have all the diffs, I simply want the average of them, so I sum all the 4 rolling dataframes, and I divide it by 4 (number of differences computed). The results should be (before dropping all N/A values):

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN',-1,-1},index=[0, 1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11])
```

Comment: Could you please provide example of your input and desired output?

Comment: @zipa, I have added a quick example step-by-step. Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure about the output after steps 1, 2 and 3? If you are sure of the output, are you sure that the output after step 1 is the sign of the difference of the moving averages?

Comment: @Yurgen Schembri - I confirm the output is correct for step 1 and 2... except that I forgot to mention I need to compute the percentage before. As follows: `df=df.pct_change()` Then I compute the sign of the difference of the moving average. Step 3 is just the average of the results of step 2; since the example is simple and only containing -1, the result should be NaN everywhere except the last two rows where I have -1, not -0.5. Here was my mistake

Comment: That makes more sense. In the first snippet, where you assign the result to a new DataFrame, try replacing with: 

`result = pd.concat([calc(df, T, t) for T in lst for t in lst_2], axis=1).mean(axis=1)`.

To cater for NaNs, you can assign np.nan to all rows where there are NaNs before calculating the mean.

Comment: @Yurgen Schembri - the solution looks fine for the example thank you. What would happen if the initial df has more than one column? In my real work, df has several columns and I want to do the same exercise for each column of df separately and to gather all the results in a single dataframe. Running your code returns a single pandas series (and should ideally return a dataframe with same dimension as initial df). Thank you!